# How to start mongoshell for local DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, batch-file

I am having inexplicable trouble connecting to local MongoDB database - I am trying to start the Mongo Shell for this local DB

right now my script (connect_to_dev_DB.bat) is this:

```
mongo --dbpath ./data
```

but this isn't right

here are the directories in Eclipse with the script opened

[image]

wth

Comment: `mongo` is the shell. `mongod` is the server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the command

```
$ mongo --shell
```

so that you can have a mongo shell to the default db. Then you can switch to your favorite db, say `mydb`, by giving the command

```
> use mydb
```

The association with the dbpath that you are trying to make should be there for `mongod` (i.e. the mongo daemon).

Of course, `mongo` should be in your `PATH` variable, otherwise, just give the absolute path where you can find the command. Moreover, if you want to connect directly to the db of your choice, you can do so with the following:

```
$ mongo --shell localhost/mydb
```

Finally, once you acquire the mongo shell, you can view all the databases using

```
> show dbs
```

Comment: If you look at the `/data` folder in the screenshot which contains the database files, then it becomes clear that the OP wants to start a "server" process with their script. That and the supplied arguments. They just got the executable name wrong.

Comment: Thanks Neil. To be honest, I did not pay much attention to the screenshot, but I did mention the difference between `mongo` and `mongod`. Thanks for upvoting too.